# Why am i getting this Rstudio Knitting Problem

Tags: r, rstudio, knitr

While trying to knit a PDF, I am getting the message that there is "no such file or directory." Unsure what to do or how to set directory. They folder that I have the data set in does in fact exist.

[image]

Comment: Check if your working directory is what you expect it to be in relation to the path to your CSV file. Maybe create a separate rmarkdown file with just `getwd()` in a code chunk and see what gets returned in the knitted document.

Answer (score 0):

The execution halts at line 15. Does the read.csv in that line work properly? perhaps there is a problem with your read.csv function because of the path to the file is broken or does not exist.

Try setting working directory before that with setwd() and then refer to the name of the file and extension in the read.csv function.